# Does the 'Element: keydown event' register the same 'number' on a slower CPU compared to a faster CPU, when holding down a key for a period of time?

Tags: javascript

So, when I hold down a key, for lets say 2 seconds, and I call a function for that event which performs some action. Is that action being performed the same amount of times on a faster CPU compared to a slower CPU? Does the faster system register the same number of 'keydowns' compared to the slower one?

I'm trying to get a user input and move an object on a canvas. And I am unsure how it'll work regarding an action when a key is being pressed down. I'm afraid it'll perform differently on various systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Key repeat is usually handled at the operating system level, and can be set by the user, so your code shouldn't rely on it happening at any particular speed.

If you're okay with that, go ahead and use the OS-defined (and/or user-defined) key repeat.

If you aren't, though, you can easily set up your own "repeat" using `keydown` and `keyup`. Here's an example that doesn't care what key you hold down (only use one key with it, it's just a very basic demo), it will repeat the action roughly every half a second:

```js
let nextRepeat = 0;
document.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
    if (nextRepeat === 0) {
        // Start repeating
        doKeyThing();
        nextRepeat = setInterval(doKeyThing, 500);
    }
});
document.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
    clearInterval(nextRepeat);
    nextRepeat = 0;
});
function doKeyThing() {
    console.log("Key down");
}
```

```html
Click on this text, then hold down a key (then release it).
```

Here's a slightly more complicated example that handles multiple keys being down and using different timers for them:

```js
const headRow = document.querySelector("table thead tr");
const bodyRow = document.querySelector("table tbody tr");
for (let digit = 0; digit < 10; ++digit) {
    headRow.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<td>${digit}</td>`);
    bodyRow.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<td id="display-${digit}">0</td>`);
}

const keyTimers = Array.from({ length: 10 }, () => ({ timer: 0, count: 0 }));

document.addEventListener("keydown", ({ key }) => {
    if (key >= "0" && key <= "9") {
        const entry = keyTimers[+key];
        if (entry.timer === 0) {
            const handler = () => {
                handleKey(key);
            };
            handler();
            entry.timer = setInterval(handler, 250);
        }
    }
});

document.addEventListener("keyup", ({ key }) => {
    if (key >= "0" && key <= "9") {
        const entry = keyTimers[+key];
        clearInterval(entry.timer);
        entry.timer = 0;
        updateEntryDisplay(key, entry);
    }
});

function handleKey(key) {
    const entry = keyTimers[+key];
    ++entry.count;
    updateEntryDisplay(key, entry);
}

function updateEntryDisplay(key, entry) {
    document.getElementById(`display-${key}`).textContent = entry.count;
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
table {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
th, td {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 10%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p>Click in the document, then hold down any of the digit keys on your keyboard (on their own, or in combinations).</p>
<table><thead><tr></tr></thead><tbody><tr></tr></tbody></table>
```

---

**Note:** As [Kaiido points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72967016/does-the-element-keydown-event-register-the-same-number-on-a-slower-cpu-com#comment128877472_72967092), you can tell if a `keydown` is for the initial press or a repeat by using the [`repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/repeat) property. I didn't use it above just because of the way the logic worked in my head, but that's a detail of the examples, you might well use it in what you're doing.

Comment: Instead of setting `nextRepeat` to 0 you can check for the `.repeat` property of the keydown event.

Comment: @Kaiido - Oh, that's cool. For me, I'd rather keep it as is so there's no chance of my starting two timers for the same key (weird window focus stuff, etc.), but that's really useful info, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your reply and explanation. So the example you made would be more suitable for a game I suppose as well right? Since you don't want people moving at different speeds cause of the OS defined key repeat. @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @rewfsdv - Right, exactly, and you set the speed of repeat by the delay on the interval.

Comment: Yes, anyway to use the .repeat property you'd need to check for a single `.key`, otherwise pressing two keys simultaneously would start two intervals and one is unstoppable. @rewfsdv generally in games you have at least one or two time loops, to update the rendering and the world logic. So what you do is that a bit like here you listen for both keydown and keyup, but instead of starting an interval you just set flags to tell if a key is down or not. Then in the world logic update you check which flags are raised at this tick.